# Как правильно вывести данные из БД в listbox используя combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал вот такую таблицу для вывода данных. подключил программно базу данных.

[image: Новая форма]

хотел чтобы при выборе Item'a из этого combobox выводились именно те данные которые соответствуют названию Item. но ничего не выводится. если делаю через кнопку то выводится вообще вся таблица и то не в правильном порядке.После даты нули еще какие то появляются, хотя везде в настройках изменил формат даты.

[image: Получается так]

[image: Исходная таблица]

```
namespace HomeTest
{
    public partial class statistics : Form
    {
        string income = "Доход";
        string expense = "Расход";

        public static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\\User\\Desktop\\Домашнее задание\\База данных.mdb";

        private OleDbConnection myConnection;

        public statistics()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
            myConnection.Open();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        /*private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //ТАК НЕ ВЫВОДИТСЯ НИЧЕГО
        {
            string query = "SELECT Тип, Категория, Дата, Сумма  FROM Accounting ORDER BY Id";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            if (comboBox1.Items.Contains(income)) // ТАК НЕ МОГУ ПОЛУЧИТЬ ВЫВОД В LISTBOX
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString() + "  " + reader[1].ToString() + "  " + reader[2].ToString() + "  " + reader[3].ToString() + "  " + reader[4].ToString() + "  " +
                    reader[5].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }*/

        private void statistics_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT Тип, Категория, Дата, Сумма  FROM Accounting ORDER BY Id";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read()) // так выводится вся таблица но в неправильном порядке.
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString() + "  " + reader[3].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть следовали одному стилю. Если колонки называются по-русски: `Тип, Категория, Дата, Сумма` , то не должно быть колонки `Id` и таблицы `Accounting`, а все надо именовать русскими названиями. У вас в запросе нет условия для фильтрации, надо использовать `WHERE Тип = 'Доход'` или `WHERE Тип = 'Расход'` в зависимости от выбора в комбобоксе.

Comment: `После даты нули еще какие то появляются, хотя везде в настройках изменил формат даты.` - это потому, что  вы пишете не приводя к нужному типу `reader[3].ToString()`, а у ридера есть куча методов, типа `GetString()`, `GetInt32()`, `GetDatеTime()` их надо применять.

Comment: метод GetDateTime() не добавляется к reader. появляется ошибка

Comment: Что значит не добавляется? У вас подсказки работают в студии? Пишешь `reader`ставишь точку и появляется полный список доступных методов и свойств этого класса, выбираешь нужный.

Comment: да работают подсказки. но GetDateTime() не показывается. выходит CS1061 "object" не содержит определения "GetDateTime", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "GetDateTime", принимающий тип "object" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: тогда используйте `Convert.ToDateTime(reader[3])`

Comment: теперь это выходит System.InvalidCastException: "Недопустимое приведение "Int32" к "DateTime"."

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(reader[2])`, а сами вы конечно догадаться и исправить не можете?

Comment: почему reader[2]? ведь массив даты находится в reader[3]?

Comment: `почему reader[2]? ведь массив даты находится в reader[3]?`, а вы знаете с какого индекса начинается отсчет в массивах, тогда сразу поймете)

Comment: @Yaroslav, если не ошибаюсь отсчет начинается с 0.

Comment: ок, так почему там должно быть `reader[3]`?

Comment: а столбец Id не идет в счет?

Comment: все равно не помогает Convert.ToDateTime(). часовые нули так и остались после даты.