# Как решить возникшую ошибку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using HomeTest.База_данныхDataSetTableAdapters;

namespace HomeTest
{
    public partial class statistics : Form
    {
        public static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\\User\\Desktop\\Домашнее задание\\База данных.mdb";

        private OleDbConnection myConnection;

        public statistics()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
            myConnection.Open();
        }

        private void statistics_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        private void statistics_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT Тип, Категория, Дата, Сумма  FROM Accounting ORDER BY Id";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString() + "  " + reader[3].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

при запуске программы на компьютере где делалась программа ошибок нет. но если с другого компьютера при нажатии на кнопку "Статистика" на форме возникает ошибка в виде необработанного исключения в коде
 myConnection.Open();
в чем может быть причина?

код самой кнопки "Статистика" в главной форме такой

```
private void stButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    statistics st = new statistics();
    st.Owner = this;
    st.Show();
}
```

P.S. В качестве базы данных используется Access.

[image: Главная Форма]

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: Вы уверены, что путь `d:\\User\\Desktop\\Домашнее задание\\База данных.mdb` существует на втором компьютере?

Comment: нет. я передал программу целиком с папкой куда и включена БД Access  в архиве. когда распаковал то вышла ошибка. как же тогда правильно сделать?

Comment: База лежит в том же каталоге, где исполняемый файл приложения?

Comment: попробуйте обернуть названия колонок в запросе в кавычки.

Comment: да в том же каталоге

Comment: Aziz Umarov можно поподробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: Вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580704) почитайте.

Comment: ну если в том же коталоге , измените connection String, d:\\User\\Desktop\\Домашнее задание\\База данных.mdb на База данных.mdb. Скорее всего Ваш друг запускает программу из другого каталога

Comment: @AzizUmarov как кавычки могут повлиять на `connection.Open()`? Ведь там исключение, разве нет? Прочитайте, что там в исключении написано. Разве ошибка в запросе? Нет. Зачем вы путаете автора?

Comment: я сменил ответ, после уточняющего вопроса, извините если что.

Comment: @AzizUmarov ответы лучше писать в форме для ответов, а не в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо буду иметь в виду.

Comment: @aepot я правильно понял мне нужно строку подключения заменить просто на указание папки где лежит база данных? public static string connectString = @".\Домашнее задание";

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Впрочем, вы сначала попробуйте, потом спрашивайте. :) и почитайте внимательно по ссылке выше, обратите внимание на `Application.ExecutablePath`, поищите примеры с использованием этого.

Comment: Уже попробовал не вышло) читаю дальше)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте путь к базе относительно исполняемого файла. В этом случае будет всё равно, из какого каталога запущено приложение, главное чтобы файл с базой находился в одном и том же каталоге с исполняемым файлом приложения.

```csharp
public static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.Combine(new FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath).DirectoryName, "База данных.mdb");
```

Comment: а я вот так сделал. так правильно? вроде ошибка больше не выходит. на втором комп-е открывается. но не будет ли в дальнейшем ошибок с  нажатием              ' public static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=База данных.mdb"; '

Comment: @Никита есть риск, что не будет работать, если при запуске приложения текущий каталог пользовптеля будет отличаться от местонахождения приложения. Откройте свойства любого ярлыка, и вы поймете, о чем я. Или опять же, этот момент упоминается в комментариях по той же ссылке, что я вам давал в комментарии к вашему вопросу. Попробуйте способ, что я вам дал в ответе, он в этом плане надежнее.

Comment: попробовал ваш вариант, подчеркивает Path и FileInfo.   Path - не существует в текущем контексте, FileInfo - не удалось найти тип или пространство имен.

Comment: @Никита Ой, а вы `using` добавьте нужный, студия должна подсказать как это сделать. Правый клик по подчеркнутому.

Comment: да уже добавил. спасибо  using System.IO;

Comment: @Никита я рад что всё получилось. Успехов. :)

Comment: а можете пожалуйста объяснить что значит "если при запуске приложения текущий каталог пользователя будет отличаться от местонахождения приложения"? т.е если в моем случае программа в одном месте а БД в другом?

Comment: @Никита Например приложение находится в `c:\app\app.exe`, вы запускаете `cmd`, и пишете `cd \ `. Рабочий каталог будет `c:\ `. Затем запускаете `c:\app\app.exe`, и программа не найдет базу, потому что по вашему варианту она будет искать ее `c:\База данных.mdb`.

Comment: понятно спасибо. а можете ли вы мне еще в одном вопросе помочь. вроде все варианты перепробовал но не получается все равно.

Comment: @Никита Задайте отдельный вопрос на StackOverflow, я или кто-то другой, вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: задавал уже. потерялась ссылка на него. попробовали помочь но не смогли

Comment: вот нашел ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2-listbox-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-combobox

Comment: @Никита все ранее заданные вопросы видны у вас в профиле, я посмотрел, но я не специалист по Winforms, я больше по WPF.

Comment: понятно. все равно спасибо.